# Get the full path of a file in azure synapse studio using pyspark

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I need to process a pdf file from my storage account. In the local environment, we use to get the path of the file 'C:\path\file1.pdf'. But how can I access the data in Azure storage account in the azure synapse studio pyspark(python)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Manual Method:** If you want to manually get the full path of the storage account manually.

- For ADLS GEN2 accounts: `'abfss://<FileSystemName>@<StorageName>.dfs.core.windows.net/FilePath/FileName/'`
- For Azure Blob accounts: `'wasbs://<ContainerName>@<StorageName>.blob.core.windows.net/FilePath/FileName/'`

**Automatic Method:** Here are the steps to get the full path of a file in Azure Synapse Studio using Pyspark.

You can create a linked service to connection to the external data (Azure Blob Storage/Gen1/Gen2).

**Step1:** You can analyze the data in your workspace default ADLS Gen2 account or you can link an ADLS Gen2 or Blob storage account to your workspace through "**Manage**" > "**Linked Services**" > "**New**"

[image]

**Step2:** Once a connection is created, the underlying data of that connection will be available for analysis in the Data hub or for pipeline activities in the Integrate hub.

[image]

**Step3:** Now you have successfully connected Azure Data Lake Gen2 without pass any  path.

[image]

**Reference:** [Azure Synapse Analytics - Analyze data in a storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-analyze-storage)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your storage account is linked to the azure synapse account.
2. Then navigate to the file which want to access from a pyspark notebook.
3. Then right click on that file and select "load to dataframe", few lines of code will be generated in which the path which you can use to access will be present.

Let me know if it was helpful, if u need more details I can explain in dept with few screenshots.

Happy learning!!!